# Binding XAML Visibility attribute to Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, wpf, security

In my WPF client Application I use `GenericIdentity` for security:

```
GenericIdentity MyIdentity = new GenericIdentity("Identity");
String[] MyStringArray = { "Admin", "Editor" };
GenericPrincipal MyPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(MyIdentity, MyStringArray);
```

Now I want to show/hide WPF objects according to user role.
Iv'e tried several methods such as:

```
Visibility="{Binding Source=Thread.CurrentPrincipal, Converter={StaticResource RoleToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Administrator}"
```

which make the 'value' object in the converter a String of "Thread.CurrentPrincipal", also tried:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=Thread.CurrentPrincipal, Converter={StaticResource RoleToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Administrator}"
```

And

```
Visibility="{Binding Source=Thread.CurrentPrincipal, Path=CurrentPrincipal, Converter={StaticResource RoleToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Administrator}"
```

which skip the converter entirely.
This is my first C#/.net program so I don't really have a lot of knowledge in the area, Would greatly appreciate a solution. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to access static properties, you need to use the [`x:Static` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx):

```
Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Static Threading:Thread.CurrentPrincipal},
    Converter={StaticResource RoleToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Admin}"
```

This assumes you have

```
xmlns:Threading="clr-namespace:System.Threading;assembly=mscorlib"
```

on the root element of your XAML.

Second, you don't show how you set the principal, but [you have to do it using `AppDomain.SetThreadPrincipal()`](http://www.joeseymour.net/2009/01/wpf-showdown-appdomaincurrentdomainsett.html).

Third, you set the role to `Admin`, but then check for `Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

In code-behind (C#), you need to set the `DataContext` of your control to the object that contains `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Then in XAML, you do it the second way.

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but certainly not the only one.